# Django Reset Serializer loses a file and raises validation error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Simple serializer.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()
```

The main problem is that it raises validation error, even though **I provided the file to serializer**. The view will return message that data are invalid. This behaviour seems to be wrong. The file which I clearly pass to the serialzier magically disapears which results in validation error.

class MyView(APIView):

```
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        # <QueryDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: some_file.png (image/png)>]}>
        serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        ...
```

The endpoint responses with:

```
{
  "file": [
    "This field can not be null."
  ]
}
```

This behaviour is strange to my. The docs says that `request.data` contains both `file` and `non-file` object. We can even see that in my `print`. The question is why my serialzier can't make use of it? Thie file magically disappears.

I use this serializser in my view:

```
class MyView(APIView):

    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        # <QueryDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: some_file.png (image/png)>]}>
        serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid()

        print(serializer.data)
        # {'file': None}
```

With a little bit of testing I see that even though I pass data to serializer, which containts a file. But after checking `serializer.data` it says that `file` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

serializer data will be access through serializer.validated_data

```
class MyView(APIView):

   permission_classes = ()
   parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

   def post(self, request):
      print(request.data)
      # <QueryDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: some_file.png (image/png)>]}>
     serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
     serializer.is_valid()

    print(serializer.validated_data)
```

Comment: Well. The main problem is that serializer does no pass validation even though I provide the file to it. This behaviour seems to be wrong. Your answer is not exactly What I am asking for. I edited the question to me more clear about the problem. Please edit or remove the answer.

Comment: i executed the same code, it's working for me. What is content type you setting when you are sending the file

Comment: I send it as multipart/form-data

Comment: I can get the file from request.data and operate on it. But the serialzier does not see it. And It says that there is no file.